# Recursive ROWNUM usage with transactional Method

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I have a table named `Person`, My select sql usually brings number of lets say 100K person since It takes so much time I am having readtimeout exception.
So I know that I have to use `ROWNUM` to limit the result size.

```
Class MyService {
  @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
doJob(){

  jobService.process();
}

}

Class JobService {
    public void process() {
    List<Person> personlList= jdbcQuery.query ("Select * from ... ... where rownum<1000" , ROWMAPPAR, parameter);
//Process all record list
    }
```

Everything is ok till know But I want to be sure all record lets say 100K are processed and if there is an error while processing one of the batch ,rollback should be occured.

Do I need to invode `process()` method recursively?

**Using 
Spring 3.5
Oracle 11g**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ROWNUM as shown in your query may very well not give you the results you expect. (But on the other hand it may, at least sometimes :-). ROWNUM is generated as rows are are emitted from the query, **AFTER** the WHERE clause is evaluated, but **BEFORE** any ORDER BY or HAVING clauses are applied. This can cause your query to return results which may surprise you.

Try creating the following table:

```
create table t(n number);
```

And populating it with:

```
insert into t (n)
  select n from
   (select rownum n from dual connect by level <= 2000)
   where n > 1234;
```

Thus the table will have rows with values of 1235 through 2000.

The run each of the following queries in order:

```
select *
  from t
  order by n;

select n, rownum
  from t
  where rownum < 100
  order by n;

select n, rownum as r from
 (select n
    from t
    order by n);

select n, r from
 (select n, rownum as r from
   (select n
      from t
      order by n))
  where r < 100
  order by n;
```

and observe the differences in the output you get.

For those who don't have an Oracle instance handy, [here's an SQLFiddle with the above in it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/580fe/3).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: This is all true, of course, but I think that (even if accepted), this isn't the OP's actual problem... They're asking how to keep each batch sub-task in the same transaction at the client side.

Comment: I have set the fetchsize jdbctemplate.setFetchSize() then remove ROWNUM operator. I thought that jdbctemplate gets records fetchsize  by fetchsize  until all records are taken

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to invode process() method recursively?

I wouldn't do that. Simply rewrite your code to this:

```
class MyService {

  @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
  void doJob(){

    // Continue processing within the same transaction, until process() returns false
    while (jobService.process());
  }
}

class JobService {
  public boolean process() {
    List<Person> personlList= jdbcQuery.query(
      "Select * from ... ... where rownum<=1000" , ROWMAPPAR, parameter);
    // I've changed your predicate ------^^

    // process() returns false when the above select returns less than 1000 records
    return personList.size() == 1000;
  }
}
```

Beware, though, that one of the problems that you may be experiencing is the fact that you're keeping a very long-running transaction alive. This will cause a lot of concurrency inside your database and might contribute to the batch job running slow. If you don't absolutely need an atomic batch job (everything committed or everything rolled back), you might consider running each sub-job in its own transaction.

Comment: I have set the fetchsize jdbctemplate.setFetchSize() then remove ROWNUM operator. I thought that jdbctemplate gets record fetchsize  by fetchsize  untill all records are taken

Comment: How about last records lest say last 800 record? Based on your example these record will not be processed right

Comment: @mmc18: JDBC's fetch size might indeed help here as well. In my example, all records will be processed, because the `process()` call is made at least once, or as long as the previous `process()` call processed 1000 records. So, the trailing 800 records would be processed as well, but after that, the `while` loop will stop.